# Html buttons instead of prompt

Tags: javascript, function, prompt

I want to use two div buttons instead om prompt() in this case. Is that possible? I have tried with functions but i don't get the value from the function. Here is some of my code.

```
var gaming = true

var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
var nextnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
var rounds = 1
console.log(number)
console.log(nextnumber)


while(gaming) {
var guess = prompt(More or less?");

if (guess === "more") {
    if (number <= nextnumber) {
```

Sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad topic, and I really shouldn't go near it.  But I will anyway.

Your previous version of the program was basically a console application.  It was all synchronous, and waited for user input before continuing.

Unfortunately, that's not how web pages or web applications work.  For what it's worth, that's not how a windows UI-based application works, either.  Once you add a UI, you have moved into event-driven logic flow.  Any event can happen at any time, and you have to be able to handle that.

Beyond that, and a lot of study and experimentation on your part, the only way I can help you is to spoon-feed you a little bit.  Here's a sample that will get you started.  It isn't pretty, and it has a few bugs, but it will let you see how to do asynchronous programming.

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="console" style="height: 400px; width: 600px}"></textarea>
<div id="more">More</div>
<div id="less">Less</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var failed = false;
var number;
var nextNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
var rounds = 1;

function newRound() {
    number = nextNumber;
    nextNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52) + 1;
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "\nYou are in round " + rounds + ". The current number is: " + number + ". Guess More or Less.";
}

function checkFailed() {
    if (failed) {
        var ans = prompt("You lost.  Try again?");
        if (ans == "Yes") {
            rounds = 1;
            document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = "";
           failed = false;
            newRound();
        }
    } 
}

document.getElementById("more").onclick = function() {
    checkFailed();
    if (nextNumber >= number) {
        document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "\nGood guess!  The next number was " + nextNumber;
        ++rounds;
        newRound();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "\nSorry, you failed.  The next number was " + nextNumber;
        failed = true;
    }
};

document.getElementById("less").onclick = function() {
    checkFailed();
    if (nextNumber <= number) {
        document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "\nGood guess!  The next number was " + nextNumber;
        ++rounds;
        newRound();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "\nSorry, you failed.  The next number was " + nextNumber;
        failed = true;
    }
};

newRound();
```

You can play with it <kbd>**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/fsZJe/)**</kbd>

A few things to note:

- All of the gameplay, other than the first `newRound` is initiated by the user.  The user has to click for the game to advance.
- Some of this is similar to what you did before - declare variables and set them.  But the gameplay logic is moved in to button handlers.
- We have to handle cases of the user hitting buttons after they lost.  (There are nicer ways to do it than the way I showed you.
- We can't assume there's a console, so we fake our own.
- We make ample use of functions - not just for callbacks, but for doing routine tasks.
- Callbacks are registered by finding the element of interest and setting up a handler for its event.  There are a lot of [events](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) you can register for.
- The callbacks actually can be more complicated functions that take parameters, but it wasn't necessary for this code.